# How to access Vue 3 methods from outside

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, mapbox, vuejs3

I have defined a method in my Vue component:

```
export default {
    methods:{
        myMethod() {
          console.log("clicked");
        },
    },
}
```

I want to call myMethod from outside Vue, something like:

```
myComponent.myMethod();
```

**P.S.**
I'm trying to archive this because in Mapbox I can only define a popup with raw html, and I want to call a Vue method within a popup.

```
const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup().setHTML('<button id="button" @click="myMethod">Click here!</button>)
```

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. https://soal.github.io/vue-mapbox/

Comment: VueMapbox is not working with Vue 3 --- 

Dependencies

Vue.js 2.5+
Mapbox GL JS 0.51+
map-promisified